# delete phone number using ews

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to manage mailbox contacts in Exchange online using EWS 2.2 in PowerShell. I am able to create, delete and modify (most of the properties)

But I can not set any PhoneNumber (BusinessPhone, MobilePhone, HomePhone) to an empty value. Tried `$updateItem.PhoneNumbers[[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PhoneNumberKey]::BusinessPhone] = $null;`

and a lot of variations. Always get: "An object within a change description must contain one and only one property to modify."

I saw this post and using the code from there does not create any error message, but the phone number also isn't empty: [EWS Delete PhoneNumber Entry on Contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567877/ews-delete-phonenumber-entry-on-contact)

Any ideas how to set these field empty?

Comment: Setting the property to $null won't work in EWS (its the same problem with the type of collection used for the email addresses) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/jj585538(v%3Dexchg.80) . When you say the extended property doesn't work how are you observing the result eg have you tried using Load in you code and see the value still exits.

Comment: it's strange, because I can use $updateItem.EmailAddresses[[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddressKey]::EmailAddress1] = $null without any issues. I checked the value in my code and in Outlook. Where do I get these addresses (0x3A08) from?

Comment: Look at the Item with a MAPI editor like MfcMapi or OutlookSpy and this will show which MAPI properties are available what the tags are and whats set